# Proof Verification: Existence of Choice functions implies Countable Union of Countable Sets is Countable

Tags: set-theory

I appreciate that this question has been asked a lot, but I'm hoping that the way that this question is formulated will be distinct from the currently available options. Here's my question:

> Carefully prove, using the axioms of ZF along with the existence of choice functions, that if $A$ is a countable set whose elements are themselves countable, then $\cup A$ is countable.

---

I think I have a proof, and would be grateful if someone could provide feedback.

---

The steps I plan on proving are the following:

1) There is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\cup A$.

2) For non-empty sets X and Y, there is an injection from X to Y, if and only if there is a surjection from Y to X.

3) There is an injection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Then an application of the three of these will give the result.

---

1) Firstly, consider the collection $\mathscr{F}$ of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathscr{A} = \cup A$. This exists as a set since we may comprehend it out of the set of subsets of ordered pairs between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathscr{A}$ given by $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A}))$.

Then for each $a \in A$ we may comprehend the subset $\mathscr{F}_{a} = \{ f \in \mathscr{F} \mid \operatorname{Range}(f) = a \}$. Then since every element of $A$ is countable, $\mathscr{F}_{a} \neq \varnothing$ for any $a \in A$.

Then we may define the function $F : A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A}))$ such that $a \mapsto \mathscr{F}_{a}$.

Then, since we are assuming that sets have choice functions, in particular $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A})$ has a choice function. So there exists $F_{C} : \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A})) \backslash \{\varnothing\} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A}))$ such that $F_{C}(S) \in S$ for all $S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A})) \backslash \{\varnothing\}$.

Then, since Range$(F) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\mathscr{A})) \backslash \{\varnothing\}$, we can define the composition 
$$G = (F_{C} \circ F) : A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N} \times \mathscr{A})$$

Then $G$ is a function that takes an element $a$ of $A$ and returns a function in $\mathscr{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$ whose range is precisely $a$.

Then our original set $A$ is countable so there exists a surjective map $\ f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$. Then we define the map:

\begin{align*}
 && H:\mathbb{N}^{2} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}, && (n,m)\mapsto (G(n))(m) &
\end{align*}

Then $H \in \mathscr{A}^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$, and further suppose $\alpha \in \mathscr{A}$, then there exists $a\in A$ such that $\alpha \in a$. Then since $f$ is surjective there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n) = a$. Then $G(a)$ is a map from $\mathbb{N}$ whose range is precisely $a$, so in particular there exists a $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(G(a))(m) = \alpha$. Hence by construction $H(n,m) = \alpha$, and so $H$ is surjective.

---

2a) Now let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets and suppose first that $\ f: X \hookrightarrow Y$. Suppose that 
\begin{align*}
& F: \mathcal{P}(X) \backslash \{ \varnothing \} \rightarrow X, && F(A) \in A &&
\end{align*} 
Is a choice function for $X$ and let $x = F(X)$ (I'm not sure if this step is strictly needed?).

Then let $Y_{1}=\operatorname{Range}(f)$. Then $f$, considered as an element of $(Y_{1})^{X}$, is a bijection so there is a well defined inverse $G:Y_{1} \rightarrow X$. Then let $H = (Y \backslash Y_{1}) \times \{x\}$, then $H$ is a function that maps every element of $(Y \backslash Y_{1})$ to $x$. Then $S = G\cup H$ is a well defined function with domain $Y$ (since $(Y \backslash Y_{1}) \cap Y_{1} = \varnothing$) and clearly $S$ is surjective.

---

2b) Now suppose $f: Y \twoheadrightarrow X $ is a surjection, and let $F$ be a choice function for $Y$. Then for $x \in X$ we may comprehend the sets $Y_{x} = \{ y \in Y \mid f(y) = x\}$. Then $f$ is surjective so $Y_{x} \neq \varnothing $ for any $x\in X$. So we may construct the function $G$ that takes elements of $x$ and returns the subsets $Y_{x}$. Then $G$ is a function from $X$ in to $\mathcal{P}(Y) \backslash \{\varnothing\}$, so we may construct the composition $H = F \circ G$. Then $H$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$. Further since $f$ is a function, and so $Y_{x} \cap Y_{x'} = \varnothing$ for any distinct $x,x' \in X$, we have that $G$ is injective, and further, again since $Y_{x} \cap Y_{x'} = \varnothing$, $F$ is injective on the range of $G$. Hence $H$ is injective.

---

3) This one is an easy application of the uniqueness of the prime factorisation of elements of $\mathbb{N}$. Define $f : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $(n,m) \mapsto (2^{n+1})\cdot (3^{m+1})$. Then it is clear that $f$ is injective.

---

Then, by 2) and 3) there exists surjection $F : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Then we compose $F$ with the function $H$ we constructed in part 1) to get a surjective function $G$ whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and image is $\mathscr{A} = \cup A$. Hence $\cup A$ is countable.

---

I'm sure that this isn't the most efficient way of solving this problem, but is this a valid way of doing it with the choice function version of the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below, I use the standard abbreviation "AC" for the axiom of choice, i.e, the principle of the existence of choice functions, to use your terminology.

You don't need AC for part (2a): if $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty and $f : X \to Y$ is injective, let $x$ be any element of $X$  and define $g(y)$ to be $f^{-1}(y)$ if $y$ is in the range of $f$ and to be $x$ otherwise. Then $g : Y \to X$ is surjective.

You do need AC for part (2b). In fact, AC is equivalent to the fact that any surjection has a right inverse. However, you don't need part (2b): in (2) you just need to get a surjection of $\Bbb{N}$ onto $\Bbb{N\times N}$ from the injection of $\Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N}$ into $\Bbb{N}$ given by part (3).

So your proof is good, but you only need to appeal to AC for part (1).

Comment: But doesn’t that argument, under the surface, require the axiom of choice? Since all we’re told is that the elements of $A$ are countable. We’re are not given the functions that count them. And so in constructing this map, you are making an infinite number of choices. Which requires the axiom of choice?

Comment: I think my worry is, explicitly, how would one prove axiomatically, that the function that you are trying to construct exists as a set, without the axiom of choice?

Comment: @AdamHiggins If a set $A$ is countable, then *by definition* there exists a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to A$ which we may reasonably represent as $A=\{a_0, a_1, a_2,...\}$

Comment: You are right: brain wandering. I've updated my answer and I hope it is now useful.

Comment: @leibnewtz: but Adam is right that, if you are then just told that each set in the set of sets $A = \{A_0, A_1, \ldots\}$ is countable, you aren't given the function that maps $i$ to an enumeration of $A_i$.

Comment: @leibnewtz My point wasn't about the countability of $A$. Since we know that $A$ is countable, we can freely choose just one function $f$ that enumerates $A$ (though to write $A$ as you have assumes that $A$ is infinite, rather than just countable). The issue is choosing the functions that count the elements of $A$. This is an infinite number of choices, so requires (at least some form) of axiom of choice.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for the help! I wasn't aware that a (surjection gives reverse injection) is equivalent to the axiom of choice. Suppose I'll go and try and prove that now! Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamHiggins: Note that "surjection gives reverse injection" can be done without AC in the special case that you already have a way to well-order the domain of the surjection. This is the case when the domain is $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$: the lexicographic order is a well order.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Would you just use the well-ordering to define the injection to send each element to the minimal element of it's inverse image? (which exists since the inverse image is never empty due to subjectivity, and by properties of a function, inverse images are disjoint, and also well ordering means every inverse image has a well defined minimal element?)

Comment: @AdamHiggins: Exactly.